# Postgres SQL add key to all json array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

In my database I have table which has a column called `items`, this column has `jsonb` type and almost every record has data like this one:

```
{"items": [{"id": "item-id", "sku": "some-sku", "quantity": 1, "master_sku": "some-master-sku"}]}
```

I need to create a migration which add `type` to every item, so it should looks like this:

```
{"items": [{"id": "item-id", "sku": "some-sku", "quantity": 1, "master_sku": "some-master-sku", "type": "product"}]}
```

I must add `type` to every record, and every record looks the same.
The problem is, that i have about milion records in my table, and I cannot iterate every item and add new `type` because it can take too long time and my deploy script may crash.

Guys, how can i do that in the simplest way?

Comment: Will it always be `"type": "product"` or will the value of `"type"` potentially have some other value? If so, where do you get it from?

Comment: @eurotrash it will be always `product`

Answer (score 1):

As long as the format/content is always more or less the same, the fastest way to do it would probably be as a string operation, something like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REGEXP_REPLACE(your_field::TEXT, '\}(.+?)', ', "type": "product"}\1', 'g')::JSONB
WHERE your_field IS NOT NULL;
```

Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fsHoFKz9szpmV5aF4dt7r/1

This just checks for any `}` character which is followed by something (so we know it's not the final one from the "items" object, and replaces it with the missing key/value (and whatever character was following).

Of course this performs practically no validation, such as whether that key/value already exists. Where you want to be between performance and correctness depends on what you know about your data.

Comment: I can have more than one item in items collection

Comment: @DawidSajdak Is that the only variation? Other than that the structure is always `{"items":[<zero or more item objects here>]}` and nothing further?

Comment: @DawidSajdak I've updated it to handle any number of objects in the items array.

Comment: it may works, but it is very dangerous solution, but thanks for helping me ;)

Comment: lol true but if you want safety you'll have to use PG's json functions which will be slower. Speed vs safety, your choice.

Comment: I always choose safety ;)